# way to check for if sql row exists?

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is this

i am fetching a mysql row via this

```
                $sql_istorrenthere = $this->query_silent("SELECT media_type
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media WHERE
                auction_id='" . $item_details['auction_id'] . "'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_istorrenthere);
```

and then calling it with this

```
if ($row['media_type'] == 4) 
{

        $display_output = GMSG_TORRENT;}
        else
        {
        $display_output = GMSG_NOTORRENT;
        }
}
```

however, media_type has multiple values, (1,2,3,4)
how to write it so that it checks if 4 exists? because now i believe it is checking if media_type equals 4 and that is false, which is giving me the wrong display_output

Comment: for some reason the suggested method $row['media_type'] == 4, returns the wrong display_output; yet when i use $row['media_type'] > 0, it works, what could be the issue?

Comment: i am getting this with using var_dump; array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["media_type"]=> string(1) "1" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql_num_rows to determine if any rows were returned, and this works by adding a search condition in your query adding " AND media_type = 4" to the end

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql_istorrenthere)) {

} else {

}

// You can loop through records by doing the following, this prints out every media type :)
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_istorrenthere)) {
    echo $row['media_type'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: No - the examined row could have had the other value of media_type with the 4 value right behind it.

Comment: All he really needs to do is add a where media_type = 4 in his query, and this approach works

Comment: My first thought was that all he needed was an additional condition, but his PHP code should nevertheless work but he says it doesn't. This led me to believe his media_type column is in fact a CSV list of type ids. Not sure. Op?

Comment: The thing with his PHP code is that he's only fetching one record, which may or may not have media_type = 4, if his code iterated through all of the rows returned, then I would agree with that possibility. His code may work sometimes, and may not work others, depending on whether or not the most recent record has media_type = 4 or not

Comment: i thought using mysql_fetch_array would return all the selected rows?

Comment: Nope, you have to loop through the results, I'll attached it to my original answer

Comment: after i figured out what you meant i got it!!

Comment: I'm very glad you were able to figure it out :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Comment the next line after you get what it is
@print ("Value of media type is: >>>".$row['media_type']."<<<"); // Line to be commented

if (isset($row['media_type']) && $row['media_type'] == 4) {
  $display_output = GMSG_TORRENT;
}
else {
  $display_output = GMSG_NOTORRENT;
}
```

To fetch all media types:

```
<?php
$sql_istorrenthere = $this->query_silent("SELECT media_type FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_istorrenthere)) {
// Comment the next line after you get what it is
  @print ("Value of media type is: >>>".$row['media_type']."<<<"); // Line to be commented

  if (isset($row['media_type']) && $row['media_type'] == 4) {
    $display_output = GMSG_TORRENT;
  }
  else {
    $display_output = GMSG_NOTORRENT;
  }

}
```

Comment: for some reason the suggested method $row['media_type'] == 4, returns the wrong display_output; yet when i use $row['media_type'] > 0, it works, what could be the issue?

Comment: getting this with var_dump; array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["media_type"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: that means $row['media_type'] = 1, in this case our if will return false because it is not 4, it is 1 so it will skip to executing the code in the else block;

Comment: why does it fetch only 1 result? how to make it fetch all the results of media_type?

Comment: $sql_istorrenthere = $this->query_silent("SELECT media_type FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media");

Answer (score 0):

You can just add on "AND media_type = '4'" to your query.  But you really should use paramaterized queries.

Once your query has "AND media_type = '4'" you can check RowCount.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways, but here's one idea.

```
$media_type_ids = explode(',', $row['media_type']);
if (array_search(4, $media_type_ids) !== FALSE) {
    // found
}
```

It could be possible to even do this in-situ in the database query ... potentially.

Comment: If it's stored as a comma-separated text string, might be able to pull out the value 4 with regular expressions.  SELECT media_type REGEXP ',*4,*'; should only return rows with a 4 as one of the options. Can you provide an example of the row you're trying to return?